# Cannot position button content neither with anchor nor with justify

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ttk

I have dynamic button label, which changes everytime you click it. The problem is, when text on the button changes, the same goes with button width. For this reason I set fixed width for my button.

After that, another problem appeared. Content is centered within button, so on every change image and label move a bit. For this reason I tried to position everything to the left side to reduce content trembling.

I looked through docs and found that button widget supports anchor option to position content. However, when I try it, I'm getting error:

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-anchor"

I found another option, justify, but result is the same:

> _tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-justify"

Anyone knows how to deal with it? I'll share my code with you:

```
self.btnServiceIo = ttk.Button(
    top_buttons_frame,
    text="Usługa automatyczna",
    image=self.ioBtnImg_off,
    compound=tk.LEFT,
    width=30,
    justify=tk.LEFT,
    anchor='w')
self.btnServiceIo.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
self.btnServiceIo.bind("<ButtonRelease>", self.IObuttonToggle)
```

(I don't use justify and anchor at the same time, I just posted them together to show you the way I'm using it)
I'll post the picture of my app for your attention. My client would like to have not only toggle image which states the status of some service, but also text information nearby.
[image]

Comment: Your question would be better if you included a small [mcve].

Comment: tkinter buttons support anchor and justify, but you're using a ttk button.

Answer (score 2):

For ttk buttons you can set the anchor option in the ttk style, see the [anchor entry on this page](https://web.archive.org/web/20190528102126/http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html).

So for example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

root = tk.Tk()

s = ttk.Style()
s.configure('TButton', anchor=tk.W)

buttonImage = Image.open('test.png')
buttonPhoto = ImageTk.PhotoImage(buttonImage) 

btnServiceIo = ttk.Button(
    root,
    text="Usługa automatyczna",
    image=buttonPhoto,
    compound=tk.LEFT,
    width=30)
btnServiceIo.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Yeah, you posted the answer while I started reading docs explanation about ttk Button at http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Button.html

Answer (score 0):

Answer from @fhdrsdg was almost perfect, but it messed with some of my simple buttons with text only, centered in the button. I had to make dedicated style for my button as following:

```
# Access ttk style object
s = ttk.Style()

# Set dedicated style for button, derived from main button class
s.configure('service-io.TButton', anchor=tk.W)

self.ioBtnImg_off = tk.PhotoImage(file='../img/io.png')
self.ioBtnImg_on = tk.PhotoImage(file='../img/io_on.png')
self.btnServiceIo = ttk.Button(
    top_buttons_frame,
    text="Usługa automatyczna",
    image=self.ioBtnImg_off,
    compound=tk.LEFT,
    width=30,
    style='service-io.TButton' # use dedicated style
    )
```